# Prevent excel from activating new objects (Sheets, Charts, Workbooks)

Tags: excel, charts, vba

Okay, I have an excel macro that processes a lot of data and makes a lot of charts.  I inherited the code from a guy that recently retired, while the code functions it is very inefficient so I am rewriting it.  One of the things I am trying to fix is he activated/selected everything.  I prefer to use references and never select/activate anything.

But I am running into a problem that when I create a new workbook or chart, it will steal focus from the original workbook.  This is annoying, because I usually don't add the workbook object in my references for my main workbook.

For example, when I use these lines, the new chart/workbook becomes active

`Set wb = Workbooks.Add` Or `Set wC = wb.Charts.Add`

I then use `Workbooks(FileName).Activate` to reactivate the original workbook

I find it annoying to have to do this every time, and was wondering if there was a way to prevent the new objects from becoming active.

Edit: I just realized that other actions cause the charts to steal focus, like moving the chart with this command `wC.Move After:=wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.Count)`

Comment: Don't think its possible when you use .Add. You can activate your original sheet using Thisworkbook.Activate

Comment: If you don't want to see the switches, use `Application.ScreenUpdating=False`   Nothing you can do to prevent the other objects being activated though.

Comment: I always use `Application.ScreenUpdating=False` but I am getting problems elsewhere when I try to use something like `Sheets(1).Cells(3,2)=X` it'll be in the wrong workbook and given an error.  I have been adding `Thisworkbook.Activate` everywhere, but I was hoping there was a way to avoid the problem to begin with.

Comment: Better than re-activating your workbook everywhere is to fully qualify all references to include the workbook object. That is simply the best way to avoid errors when dealing with multiple workbooks.

Comment: [This is worth reading](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10718179/2521004)

Comment: Rachel, I agree that probably is the best way of going about it, instead of reactivating the main workbook, just to avoid adding the WB object.  Especially since once I got deeper into the code, I found that there are some shapeobjects that will not get put in the correct location unless you make them active and turn on screenupdating, so I am bouncing around much more than I would like (would prefer to never activate anything).

Answer (score 1):

If you declare an old worksheet after a new one I believe this accomplishes what you want. For example,

```
Dim newWst As Worksheet
Dim oldWsk As Worksheet

Set newWst = Worksheets.Add
Set oldWst = Worksheets("Sheet1")

Cells(1, 1) = "Test"
```

worked for me. It added "Test" to the old worksheet.

Comment: That is an interesting work around, not sure it is better than using Thisworkbook.activate, but it is an alternative.